# how to configure windows login to get OTP as password

Tags: windows, active-directory, authentication, java, radius

I searched a little and understand that its possible,But i couldn't find any clue of how to do it.Also can i use any server that works or it must be something like SafeNet's blackShield server?
**What i'm looking for is not how to develop it.I'm looking for architecture model or a document that i couldn't find about what it needs and how to integrate the authentication server whether its developed by my company or any other company with windows**.problem is i don't know what to look for.it must be with Radius?
PS: I'm a developer who works on a AAA application.We have a server for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an old concept of Microsoft which let the OTP server enroll a short lived logon certificate to the Windows Client. Thus the user on the windows client will in fact use PKINIT to get his kerberos ticket - use the certificate to login.
https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/gg637807(v=ws.10).aspx

You still need to setup a CA. The OTP server must be capable of requesting a certificate on behalf of the logging in user...

Thus, this is often implemented in another way. Also [the solution I developed(!) and work with](https://privacyidea.org) works in a different way.
On the client you install an additional Credential Provider. In this case the [privacyIDEA Credential Provider](https://netknights.it/en/produkte/privacyidea-credential-provider/) first verifies the OTP value against the privacyIDEA server. If this succeeds then the credential provider uses the windows password to perform a normal domain login based on the windows passwords.
This works pretty smooth without setting up complicated environments - no PKI.

The drawback of such an approach is that

- the user does not get rid of the domain password
- the kerberos ticket is still issued based on the domin password
- offline functionalities are limited.

But on the other hand, if you are going to setup your CA/PKI as Microsoft suggests, why not enroll smartcards in the first place? It is a great solution!

I think there are new concepts for OTP, I am curious about other answers.

Comment: but we have something like the Idea server and want to integrate it with windows.i want to know where to go and what settings needed to change?for example is it in the control panel\...?

Comment: You should find a howto to create you own "Credential Provider".

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to replace Windows password with an OTP. 
Another 3rd party alternative is Rohos Logon. A variety of methods and policies: you can setup OTP config per user/per group, use OTP by SMS/Email. Combine OTP + tokens, Yubikey OTP vs Google Auth OTP. Enroll OTP via PowerShell. It allows to replace password with OTP (as 1FA method), but still password will be used in a background by Rohos crednetial provider that works on each workstation and OTP authentication server on DOmain Controller + AD schema extensions. Offline workstations are also supported.

Comment: Hi AleSil, please take a look [here](https://serverfault.com/help/promotion)